# workflow for customing bootstrap for use with ASP.NET Core

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

The great advantage of bootstrap is that you can create cool looking websites without involving a graphic designer in generating CSS. I want to separate the work of graphic design from website development so propose the following workflow:

```
1. Download latest Bootstrap Source to a VS2015 project used for creating a Bootstrap distributable (say bootstrapfactory)
2. Download Variables.less and Theme.less from a site like http://bootstrap-live-customizer.com/ 
3. Use bootstrapfactory to create Bootstrap distributable using the downloaded Variables.less and Themes.less
4. Copy distributables from bootstrapfactory to Target Project's wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\dist
```

In this way I am obtaining bootstrap from the official source and then adapting it for my needs. This seems a better way of working than just downloading bootstrap.css as created by tools like bootstrap-live-customizer.

Unfortunately the bootstrap documentation doesn't give specific details for using VS2015 to create a distributable from the source files. Can anyone make any suggestions here?

I would particularly like a gulpfile.js that can be used in my bootstrapfactory project to build the distributables using Task Runner Explorer. This seems like a very common requirement.

Comment: Typically you would just download a copy of Bootstrap's core CSS (usually through the Bootstrap Nuget Package), then create a second, custom CSS file that you also include the project. Make sure your custom CSS file is loaded after Bootstrap, so your custom code will override Bootstrap when selectors have the same level of specificity.

Comment: My point is that I want to separate the work of graphic design from website development. I proposed the workflow as a way of integrating the graphic design work with my Website project work. I can't ask a graphic designer to create a CSS to override bootstrap styles, but I can ask him to use http://bootstrap-live-customizer.com and then send me the variables.less, theme.less files. I then need to setup a simple way of rebuilding the bootstrap.css (and other distribs) using these files - hence the bootstrapfactory project.